# Using ANOVA after a GLM?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, anova

I am analysing data using a GLM. In some GLM-s data is binary while in others the response variable is count data. I want to know if it is necessary to use an ANOVA after constructing the GLM model. Or is it enough to report the p-values of the GLM-s?

Comment: That depends on the hypothesis you are interested in testing.

Comment: I just want to see the effect of one variable on the other, for example the effect of prey abundance on the number of weasels. I am not planning to check for differences between samples

Comment: You can test this within the GLM framework. With the kinds of data you describe, the ANOVA assumptions will not typically hold.

Comment: Thank you @Glen_b. I can then leave the p-values of the GLM. There is no need to explain the results via an ANOVA?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by "explain the results via an ANOVA" but any calculation you're planning to use an ANOVA for can be done within the GLM framework. (If you're using a GLM how could the ANOVA assumptions hold?) ... what would you have done with ANOVA?

Comment: I think the idea of using an ANOVA after a model is not very clear in my head. At my university they would tell us to always use an ANOVA after an LM but I would never understand why since the LM already gives the results we want. @Glen_b

Comment: It depends on what that ANOVA is doing. For example, if you want to test a multilevel *factor* variable in a linear regression with other predictors. you can't just look at the plain linear regression output. You could fit a sequence of linear models to test hypotheses like that (and call `anova` in R to get a p-value). Well you can do something quite similar with a GLM, but it's *analysis of deviance* and based on asymptotic chi-square tests rather than small-sample F results. You're not very clear about what things you want to find out.

Comment: For example for binary data, I want to see the effect of camouflage (YES, NO) on detection (1= detected, 0= undetected). Also I want to see the effect of prey abundance on the number of weasels as well as snow cover duration on the number of individuals. In other terms how is number of weasels varying with these two factors. Finally, I did an interaction between snow and prey abundance and saw the effect on weasel numbers. I got the p-values from the GLM and I saw which variable is affecting detection and weasel numbers. If I got the p-values, then it is not necessary to use an ANOVA? @Glen_b

Comment: prey abundance and snow cover duration are numeric (or are they categorical)?

Comment: They are numeric. Prey abundance consists of continuous values and snow cover duration (in days) is discrete. @Glen_b

Comment: Then yeah it sounds like it's possible to see from the results of the various GLMs, though I'm not clear on all the details from this brief discussion.

Comment: For the interaction for example, this is what I had `glm(formula = nivalis ~ voles * snow, family = quasipoisson, data = prey)

voles:snow   0.0024326  0.0008568   2.839   0.0363 *`   I think it is clear that there is an effect of the interaction on the weasel numbers. @Glen_b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ANOVA test, of the regression equation, is essentially a test to determine if your proposed model is "better" than simply modelling the outcome using only the mean (of the outcome).

As per your comments nothing is forcing you to run ANOVA style testing, but most standard software will compute it for you regardless. In your case it does not seem in particular relevant.

Comment: Thank you @Repmat. So ANOVA can also be conducted on GLM models which are constructed on binary data?

Comment: @kamel yes indeed, typically this is referred to as the chi square test of the  (logit) model.

Comment: Usually it would be called an analysis of deviance.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I will then remove the ANOVA analysis from the paper since the GLM already proved the effect of one variable on the other.